# Late 2007 MacBook: can't boot from USB/DVD to install Windows 7

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, startup, unix

I have a late 2007 MacBook with Ubuntu.

I want to install Windows 7, but can't even reach the installation.

I've tried to boot from a USB and DVD. Both don't work.

When the computer starts, I hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key... nothing.

Then I've read somewhere that <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> would help... nothing happend.

Looking forward for your advice.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Have you tried pressing and holding the "C" key while starting up? That should instruct the Mac to start up from a CD/DVD.

Comment: jaume - I've tried after your comment, but nothing happend. The Mac pops the DVD out and stay with a black screen.

Comment: Thank you for testing. Could it be that the DVD is not bootable? Have you tested it with another computer?

Comment: [Officially](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016), your model Mac requires the Windows 7 DVD to be 32 bit and contain SP1. Your model Mac can not boot any version of Windows from the USB port. Unofficially, you may be able to install Windows 7 by using Grub to BIOS boot the installer from the internal drive